# Adding int property, EF keeps making it nullable column?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm adding a int property called Order to an existing entity that already has records in the DB tables.

```
public class Page : Content
{
    // ...
    public int Order { get; set; }
    // ...

}
```

However, when I run "update-database", it's adding the column as nullable with a default value of null. I tried using [DefaultValue(0)], as well as setting the default in the constructor. Neither work.

How can I add a column/property to an existing set of data and have it populate as a non-null value of 0? Thanks.

Comment: Can we see where Order is being used?

Comment: It's not used anywhere at the moment. I merely added it as a property. I do have a second int property that does not have any special attributes or initializations, but that property was created as not null in the DB. Though, that was there before I started adding content.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SQL Server:

If you just insert the column from SQL Server management studio user interface, this is the DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
    [Order] int NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_MyTable_Order DEFAULT 0 FOR [Order];
```

The column content is null.
If you specify that the column should not be null this is the DDL

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
    [Order] int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Order DEFAULT 0
```

And it works as expected (column content = 0)

Running manually this query

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
    [Order] int CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Order DEFAULT 0
```

The column content is null

Finally running manually this query

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
    [Order] int CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Order DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES
```

The column content is 0

=== About EF

For sure, the behaviour depends on the EF Provider you are using (I suppose SQL Server).

The strange thing is that SQL Server 2014 (EF Provider for SQL Server have different support for about every SQL Server version) is that if you specify default WITHOUT Required attribute EF Provider generates the column as not nullable and the field creation query is

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD [Order] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Where does this behaviour come from? EF or EF Provider?

Debugging the provider it seems that is EF that assert that the column should not be null (only specifing Default).

So, if you specify Default you can omit Required.

But now, why in your case does not work?
**I think** there's something wrong in your migrations.

For make may tests I added this column

```
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Order { get; set; }
```

I use this Migration configuration (everything automatic so many people thinks - me as well - that is no good for production)

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BloggingContext, BloggingContextMigrationConfiguration>(true));



internal sealed class BloggingContextMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContextMigrationConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

=== Another result

Actually I could not find a way to generate something like this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
    [Order] int CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Order DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES
```

and I think that EF 6.x is not possible to do it...

Answer (score 1):

That's because of inheritance. Not all properties in derived types can be defined as not-nullable, because types in the upper level of hierarchy doesn't have those properties.

Comment: Does that mean it's ok to leave fields non-nullable on derived types, because EF will make the field nullable under the hood anyway?  That would be nice, so that all the fields on the derived types don't have to be nullable properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your entity framework diagram
2. Find your class and delete it
3. Add class again to entity framework

I had the same issue and this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have two questions:

1. How to add a column/property to an existing set of data ?
2. How to make column non-null?

The 2nd I think is `Required`

```
[Required]
public int Order { get; set; }
```

The first question -- I do not know how to express it.

Comment: It's not necessary to keep repeating that you can't comment. That makes a bad impression. Also, don't use code blocks for lists.